# How to use alignItems="center", justifyContent="center" and position="absolute" in react native web

Tags: styles, react-native-web

I am using react native 0.63.3 for web application development now.

I try to use following code, but very strange.

<View style={{
alignItems: 'center',
justifyContent: 'center',
}}>

&

<View style={{
position: 'absolute'
}}>

First code, alignItems and justifyContent styles are removed. So I changed the styles to other values such as "flex-end", that was working well.

As well position style is not working with "absolute" value. But other values of this style are working well.

Who can help me

Answer (score 0):

Basically justifyContent is used to align by vertical and alignSelf is used to align by horizontal. For example, in order to center a box inside a box. You would do like this:

```
<View style={{width:300,height:100,backgroundColor:'blue',justifyContent:'center'}}>
<View style={{width:50,height:50,backgroundColor:'red',alignSelf:'center'}}
</View>
```

If you want to align a text in the center of a box(view) horizontally, you use `textAlign:'center'`. So, in total it would look like this =>
`<Text style={{textAlign:'center',fontSize:40}}>HELLO WORLD</Text>`

If you want to align a text in the center of a box(view) with vertical and horizontal, you need to use justifyContent from the parent view and textAlign in the text like this =>

```
<View style={{height:100,width:100,justifyContent:'center'}}>
<Text style={{fontSize:30,textAlign:'center'}}>HELLO WORLD</Text>
</View>
```

You use absolute/relative if you want to have a view on top of each other without putting a View in its Parent View.
You mostly use absolute/relative on images but its totally up to you.

Summary:

JustifyContent:'center' should always go in the View(align in by vertical)

textAlign:'center' should always go in the Text(align in by horizontal but only in Text)

alignSelf:'center' should always go in the View(Align in by horizontal but only in Text)

Comment: I know the meaning of alignItems and justifyContent yet. But did you test your code in website. In first build, alignItems="center", justifyContent="center", and position="absolute" styles are removed from original styles. I would like to know why this happened.

Comment: What do you mean by 'removed from original styles'